# How do you position an element relative to centered sibling

Tags: html, css

I have a centered div inside of a container, and I want to position another element next to the centered one.

What is the best way to do this (if its possible)?
[image]

The width of the divs is determined by the text they contain and is not static.

Comment: It is possible. Does the second div need to take up all space remaining in between first div and container? If so, what's the max width ratio between first div and container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. Has the advantage of making second div fill up ***all*** the remaining space between container and first div. In short, it is responsive.

The first div has to have a width that's smaller than the containers' (or second div won't show up, with a negative width). First div can have a width in `%` of containers' width or can have a fixed width in `px` (example 3).

If you want second div to go till the very edge of container, remove the `-10px` from calc: `calc(100vw - 100%) / 2)`. I just put it there so you could see we're not hiding the excess, we're controlling the width.

```css
body {margin: 0;} 
.container {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container > * {
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.first-div {
  background-color: #696;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 60%; /* set default/fallback first div width here - fixed or % */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.second-div {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 -20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #933;
  width: calc(((100vw - 100%) / 2) - 10px);
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">
    <div class="second-div">Blog truffaut letterpress, austin butcher vinyl aesthetic.  </div>
    <h1>Example 1</h1>
    This div is 60% of container (default, set in CSS). Kale chips banjo hella swag jean shorts. Fixie meh venmo, gastropub disrupt migas 3 wolf moon PBR&B.
  </div>
  
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div" style="max-width: 30%;">
    <div class="second-div">Freegan you. Skateboard thundercats art party bushwick fashion axe. Tattooed 90's cornhole, flexitarian scenester mixtape pinterest beard fixie pabst.</div>
    <h1>Example 2</h1>
    This div is 30% of container (override by inline styling). Kale chips banjo hella swag jean shorts. Fixie meh venmo, gastropub disrupt migas 3 wolf moon PBR&B. Blog truffaut letterpress, austin butcher vinyl aesthetic. 
    
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div" style="max-width: 400px">
    <div class="second-div">Freegan you. </div>
    <h1>Example 3</h1>
    This div has a fixed width of 400px (inline styling). Kale chips. This div has fixed width, But the second one resizes responsively.
    
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't use calc() because I have to [support IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc), but the answer still contains everything I needed and does so cleanly.  Thanks for the thorough solution.

Comment: I would still use it, detect IE8 with JavaScript and change CSS on the fly for those users. And I'd add a "get a real browser, yo!" alert while at it :)

Comment: For what it's accomplishing, that would seem like excessive code.  Hopefully, with Microsoft dropping support soon, I won't have to worry about older IEs much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Updated (2nd) answer:

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  outline: 3px solid red;
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 105%;
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  div1
  <div class="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the snipped to reflect your updated question (You: The width of the divs is determined by the text they contain and is not static.
) For example: right: -210px...

Comment: This requires div2 to be a fixed width.  What if its width is determined by the text inside it?

Comment: Not anymore, check my code again :) Example: http://codepen.io/bbredewold/pen/GopZpK

Comment: Ya, sorry. Missed that comment.  I also edited mine to div2.

Comment: Nailed it with the second update.  left: 100% was the missing key.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

this should be exactly what you need. Obviously you can adjust the width and height of things as you need. The key is setting the divs inside of the container to display: inline-block;

I'm not sure how familiar you are with html and css, but here I used an external stylesheet. You can use the `<style>` tag if you prefer.

If you remove the width of the divs inside of the .container their size will be determined by their content.

Html

```
<!DOCtype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/sot.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="centered-div"></div>
        <div class="other-div"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
    .container {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 485px;
    margin-top: 3px;
} 

.centered-div {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin: auto;
}
.other-div {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: centered-div isn't centered ;)

Comment: Ohhh I see you don't want them both centered?

Comment: Here ill edit it so that it works all you need to do is position the centered one relative and the other div absolute